# Cannot find substring from input file in python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-unicode

I am trying to find  format from input file. But sometimes I get no match if I use 'r' and sometimes unicode error.

```
def extract_files(filename):
    file = open(filename, 'r')
    text = file.read()
    files_match = re.findall('<Compile Include="src\asf\preprocessor\string.h">', text)
    if not files_match:
        sys.stderr.write('no match')
        sys.exit()
    for f in files_match:
        print(f)
```

Comment: Additionally, why are you using `re` for this? If you're searching for string literals, just use `if literal in text`.

Comment: Is your error because of the backslashes '\'? Did you escape them as stated here http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/re.html . To escape a literal backslash, you have to use '\\\\'

Comment: 1. Beware of backslashes - use r"\s" or "\\s" 2. Do not use regular expression search when you are not using regular expressions; just use `'<Compile ....>' in text`

Comment: I am trying to find all the files in input file containing <Compile Include="([\w.])">, that's why I am using re. Also is above format correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to pull all the strings after `<Compile Include="` and until `">`. We can do that, but be aware this will probably break on edge cases!

```
import re

def extract_files(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as file:
        text = file.read
    matches = re.findall(r'(?<=<Compile Include=")[-.A-Za-z\\]+(?=")', text)
    # finds all pathnames that contain ONLY lowercase or uppercase letters,
    # a dash (-) or a dot (.), separated ONLY by a backslash (\)
    # terminates as soon as it finds a double-quote ("), NOT WHEN IT FINDS A
    # SINGLE QUOTE (')
    if not matches:
        sys.stderr.write("no match")
        sys.exit()
    for match in matches:
        print(match)
```

Comment: It gives error 'bad character range' and I am trying to get only file name 'src\asf\preprocessor\string.h'

Comment: @user2661518 Oops, I typo'd when I copied this over. Instead of `[.-A-Za-z\\]` do `[-.A-Za-z\\]`. If the hyphen isn't first (or last or escaped), it thinks it's a character range. I've edited my solution to reflect the change.

Comment: Thnx I understood '?=' is used to match with '"' ? What is ?<= used for  I can't grab the concept

Comment: `(?<=pattern)` is a lookbehind assertion, `(?=pattern)` is a lookahead assertion. In both cases they match a pattern that's BEHIND or AHEAD of what you're looking for, without consuming it. `(?<=fo)ob(?=ar)` matches `ob` but only in `foobar` (or I suppose `asdfajklfoobarakldjfkla`)

Comment: @user2661518 so this matches any group of the characters `A-Z`,`a-z`,`-`,`.`,`\ ` one or more times (matching as many as it can) as long as after `<Compile Include="` and before `"`.

Comment: @user2661518 sounds like a separate issue.